# TrueCrypt on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, truecrypt

I'm using Mac OS X 10.9 with OSXFUSE 2.6.2. I've created 3 virtual drives. When I click the "Dismount All" button, it takes above 10 seconds to dismount all drives, but if I use the command line "/Applications/TrueCrypt.app/Contents/MacOS/TrueCrypt -t --dismount", they are unmounted immediately. I have no idea why two versions behave so differently? I looked into the source code but didn't find any difference. Anyone can explain that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just found something really interesting. If I set “Dismount All Volumes when TrueCrypt quits” on Preference dialog, then open Terminal and type “killall TrueCrypt”, all TrueCrypt processes disppear and all volumes get dismounted successfully. I think maybe there is some kind of lock between one of the process and hdiutil? If that process happens to be killed first, the volumes can be dismounted in a second. Funny. Anyone can give some suggestion? How to solve this problem?